# Green's function for the screened Poisson equation

Tags: greens-functions, classical-field-theory, normalization

Assuming we are given a Lagrangian
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}(\phi(r),\partial^i\phi(r)) = \frac{1}{2} \partial_i\phi \partial^i\phi + \frac{m^2}{2} \phi^2 + \lambda \phi,
\end{equation}
the equations of motion obtained from the Euler-Lagrange equations are
\begin{equation}
(\Delta-m^2) \phi =  \lambda.
\end{equation}
In order to find the Green's function for this system, the standard procedure would be to impose $(\Delta-m^2)G(r) = \delta(r)$, going to Fourier space in order to get an algrbraic equation ($\Delta \rightarrow k^2$) and get $G(r)$ by performing the inverse Fourier transform.

However, assuming we know that $G \propto r^{-1}e^{-mr}$, is there a way to find the proper normalization for the Green's function directly from the equations of motion, without using the above procedure?

Comment: The normalization constant, $1/4\pi$ is the same as for the unscreened Poisson equation, *for the very same reason*. Do you remember how to get that by integrating both sides (perhaps from EM)? The $\delta$ on the r.h.s. is a 3 dimensional one!

Comment: In the unscreened case I can integrate over both sides and apply the divergence theorem, but I am having trouble to do the same thing here, as $\int_0^R m^2 r^{-1}\exp(-mr) \mathrm{d}r$ diverges.

Comment: Update: I missed the Jacobian. The question is therefore solved. I will write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrating $(\Delta-m)G(\mathbf{r}) = \delta(\mathbf{r})$ with the ansatz $G(r) = A r^{-1} \exp(-mr)$ over a sphere of radius R yields
\begin{align}
1 &= A\int_V \Delta\Big(\frac{e^{-mr}}{r}\Big)-m^2\frac{e^{-mr}}{r} \;\mathrm{d}V\\
&= A\int_V \partial_r\left[r^2\partial_r\Big(\frac{e^{-mr}}{r}\Big)\right]-m^2re^{-mr} \;\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\Omega\\
&= 4\pi A\int_0^R \partial_r\left[r^2\partial_r\Big(\frac{e^{-mr}}{r}\Big)\right]-m^2re^{-mr} \;\mathrm{d}r\\
&= -4\pi A \left[(1+mR)e^{-mR}\right]+\left[1-(1+mR)e^{-mr}\right] \\
&= -4 \pi A.
\end{align}
Therefore, $A = -\frac{1}{4\pi}$.